# download zxing jar to import into eclipse for android

Tags: android, zxing

Does anyone have a working jar of `1.6 zxing`? I tried to download it and compile blah blah blah but version 2.3 has some problem in compiling. I am downloading the trunk right now but its the trunk.

All I need to do is read a QR code, that's it!

Comment: What problems do you have while compiling?

Comment: Found it. bunch of these      [exec] C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\ZXing-1.6\zxing-1.6\android\res\values-pl\s
trings.xml:96: error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format;
 did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
     [exec] C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\ZXing-1.6\zxing-1.6\android\res\values-pl\s
trings.xml:96: error: Unexpected end tag string
     [exec] C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\ZXing-1.6\zxing-1.6\android\res\values-pt\s
trings.xml:96: error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format;
 did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?

Comment: Yes, i've seen this error too. It is related to formatted strings in resources. Still haven't any clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Android SDK problem, really. The newest SDK is slightly backwards-incompatible with the version that was current as of the 1.6 release.

However, the files in question have long since been [updated in SVN](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk) to work with the newest SDK. Use the latest code (always a decent idea).

But there is a far easier way that doesn't ever involve running into these problems or downloading any code or any versions: [integrate via Intent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).

Comment: PS: for the curious, the "fix" was to add `formatted="false"` to each XML element in the `strings.xml` files whose values contained substrings like `%s`.

Comment: The problem with integrating via intenet is that the zxing application has to be previously installed. Not a good solution if you ask me.

Comment: It easily prompts the user to download; most phones have it installed or pre-installed. But, you see the bigger downside to not going this route: you have to become a developer and expert in the codebase in your own right, and have no support this way.